# In template 'a href' adds domain to the url, making url like my_domain/my_url. How to avoid this behaviour?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a model like this:

```
class Slide(models.Model):
    slideshow = models.ForeignKey(Slideshow, verbose_name=_('slideshow'), blank=False)
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), blank=False, max_length=255)
    image = FileBrowseField(_('image'), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    url = models.CharField(_('url'), blank=True, max_length=255)
```

And in template I do:

```
{% for slide in slideshow_slides %}
    <a href="{{ slide.url }}"> -->> {{ slide.url }} </a>
{% endfor %}
```

As a result I have the **text:** `-->> google.com` and **url:** `mydomain.com/google.com`

How to get a url just `google.com` without such addition as `mydomain.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If slide.url doesn't have http:// in it then your domain url is added by default.

Comment: I new it must be something simple, but cant google it :) In 10 mins will accept the answer. Thanks.